# Total count of tests before test suite from dataprovider send to listener

Tags: java, testng

Hello guys so I have 10files and 10 tests in my suite. Each test have one DATA PROVIDER what return String[].I know how to get length of all String[] from all data providers. Lets say total count of all tests in suite is 50.This value I count @BeforeClass

My question is : How can I send this total number to my suite listener before suite start? Or right after it start? Because I want use this number to calculate my threshold for skip tests etc.

I already tried setAttribute() for ITestContext and ISuite interfaces in my test class but even if I do it @BeforeClass or in @Test then it is always null in my listener class in OnStart(ITestContext context) or OnStart(ISuite suite).

Thanks for any help in advance.

1 - this methods find how many values are in all data providers what will be used in tests

[image]

2 - here is use value what was counted in previous step and set it as suite attribute

[image]

3- in my listener class i am trying to get suite attribute but it is always null

[image]

Sorry for pictures but no code but i was unable to format it correctly.

Simply what i want is to pass this total test number to listener so i can use it and count e.g. if more then 10% test fail all other will be skip(but for this i ne to know total amount of tests).But I have this logic that is no problem but I need to know how to pass this total number of tests to listener.
Normally if I dont use data provider I just use suite.GetAllMethods() and thats it , but this is not apply for dataproviders so i need pass this total ammount of tests different way then i am used to and cant figure ut how.

Comment: Could you please share a small sample of code where you counting a 'value'. And in the code please specify where do you want this 'counted value' to go (by leaving a comment). Because even suppose you set this value to TestContext it is not fully clear how are you going to use it further (in tests, or in some before/after method), in other words - descripbe how do you see that future 'skip-on-threshold' mechanics (at least on high-level using comments in the code).

Comment: @AndreyKotov - i edited post hope it is all what you need, thanks

Comment: try this simple approach https://pastebin.com/V2sPMTwK. If it works for you, then I'll post an answer here.

Comment: This is not working for me you worked around what i need.You hold your variables in TestManager" class but i need get variable to listener.But thanks for try

Comment: Our framework cannot work like you posted.I must post variable from test class to listener and not to other class

Comment: you cannot pass anything from test method to `onStart` method of `SuiteListener`. Because method/test execution happens **after** `onStart` execution.

Comment: Ok, then how you solve problem what i have?

Comment: Ok, then how you solve problem what i have?i wven tried set my attribute in before class method but then i recieve error that i must suply isuite as parameter

Comment: you had a direct question `if more then 10% test fail all other will be skip`. In my example (shared on pastebin) we calculate `totalAmountOfPlansInFiles` in `@BeforeSuite` and set this value to `TestsManager.totalTestsCount`. And in the `MyTestListener ` you calculate failed tests and check if 10% threshold is reached. If it is reached - then skip all other tests. You said that you cannot use TestManager and framework cannot work like I posted, but actually my approach can be applied to any framework, and I am sure it suites for yours as well, maybe you could try to read it one more time.

Comment: I cannot use it due to circular dependency in our project,simply our classes comunicate between each other only via listener but i figured it out. I getting parameter in OnTestStart(ITestResult) and it is working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

In listener class I must get suite attribute in OnTestStart(ITestResult) instead of OnStart(ISuite)

```
  @Override
 protected void OnTestStart(ITestResult tr) {  
    totalTests = (Integer) tr.getTestContext().getAttribute("Total tests");        
}
```

}